# React/ES6 Webpack config won't compile to ES5

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, babeljs

I'm trying to build an React app with a server and I'm having issues with configuring Webpack. 
My server code is in an directory called **api** and the react code is an a director called **src**. 
Webpack compiler React code as it should, but when I use ES6 on my server code it fails to compile. This is my webpack config for development:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [
                path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                path.join(__dirname, 'api')
            ],
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            },
        },
        ....
```

When i try do to do:

```
import test from './test'
```

in my server code

I get this:

```
import test from './test'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
   at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
   at startup (node.js:139:18)
   at node.js:974:3
```

Comment: Use `babel-register` on the server.

Comment: Why use weback on the server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788142/webpack-for-back-end/37920356#37920356

Comment: change `loader: 'babel-loader'` to just `loader: 'babel'`

Comment: Try switching the presets for your `babel-loader`: `presets: ['es2015', 'react']`

Comment: @CallumLinington, if i do that i get:

    BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix     when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel'.