# How WebPack bundles backend code

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to use WebPack to bundle backend code. Per the suggestion of other stackoverflow answers, I used the config file described [here](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'backend.js'
  },
  externals: nodeModules
}
```

but even after reading the article explaining why we have to list all modules in `node_module` as external, I am still confused why we have to have this step and why without it, we get this error:

```
WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependencies:
```

Particularly can someone explain this paragraph and how specifically `require('express')` in `src/main.js` is an example of this problem:

> But there is a problem. Webpack will load modules from the
> node_modules folder and bundle them in. This is fine for frontend
> code, but backend modules typically aren't prepared for this (i.e.
> using require in weird ways) or even worse are binary dependencies. We
> simply don't want to bundle in anything from node_modules.

I want to better understand this step in WebPack so I am not just blindly copying the config file and being complacent that it works.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to bundle backend code? What is the gain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788142/webpack-for-back-end

maybe not now but there definitely is a gain