# How to whitelist all subdependencies with webpack-node-externals

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dependencies

I'm using webpack to bundle server assets using the [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) property.

This results in a usable client bundle, and a usable server, which is working great. However it seems that even for the server code, webpack is bundling everything within `node_modules`. I am attempting to use [`webpack-node-externals`](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) to solve this problem, seen below:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    name: "server code, output to ./server",
    entry: "./servertest.js",
    output: {
      filename: "./server/index.js"
    },
    target: "node",
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        includeClientPackages: false
      })
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "client side, output to ./public",
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
      filename: "./dist/app.js"
    }
  }
]
```

This doesn't work however as its default behavior is to exclude all node_modules from bundling, thus rendering the server useless. There is a whitelist option, for which I have included `express`, the only dependency of my small test case. It doesn't fail on express, however it fails on a dependency of express, [`merge-descriptors`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json#L43). And of course if I add merge-descriptors to the whitelist, trying to start the server will fail on another dependency of express. I surely cannot add every dependency and sub-dependency (etc etc) to this whitelist array.

#### How can I ensure all dependencies of a given `require`ment are bundled by webpack during a `target: 'node'` build?

Comment: Is it fails on webpack compilation or in app runtime after compilation? Is your snippet all of your webpack config?

Comment: @Everettss It fails at runtime. No, that's not my whole config, please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thomashibbard/38265f8df1eb93c6b8a5068fd81b28e2) for the entire config. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: [Line 145](https://gist.github.com/thomashibbard/38265f8df1eb93c6b8a5068fd81b28e2#file-__server_and_client__webpack-config-js-L145) is where I was monkeying around with the node externals.

Comment: You shouldn't exclude `express` in `nodeExternals`. I have working example of config here https://github.com/Everettss/spa-optimization/blob/stage3/webpack.config.js (this app is quite barebones with only express as node modules). This repo https://github.com/Everettss/spa-optimization contains example of how include isomorphic node. My knowledge probably ends here. I wish you good luck.

Comment: @1252748 Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @prograhammer No I decided bundling server code is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this, I created a small helper, [`datwd`](https://github.com/kmjennison/datwd) to get a list of all subdependencies for specific packages:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const includeSubdependencies = require('datwd')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      // Will include "cookies" and its dependencies; for example:
      // `['cookies', 'depd', 'keygrip', 'tsscmp']`
      allowlist: includeSubdependencies(['cookies'])
    })
  ]
```

It relies on `npm ls` under the hood. Source code:

```js
/* eslint-disable global-require, import/no-dynamic-require */

const { execSync } = require('child_process')

/**
 * Returns a flat array of all Node module dependency names for the entire
 * dependency tree, optionally filtered by top-level modules. Requires NPM
 * and for dependencies to be installed.
 *
 * @param {Array} moduleFilter - An optional array of top-level module names
 *   whose dependencies should be included. If specified, any other modules'
 *   dependencies will be excluded.
 * @return {String[]} An array of module names
 */
const getAllDependencies = (moduleFilterInput = []) => {
  const moduleFilter = Array.isArray(moduleFilterInput)
    ? moduleFilterInput
    : [moduleFilterInput]

  // Get the full dependency tree using NPM, excluding dev dependencies
  // and peer dependencies.
  const dependencyTree = JSON.parse(execSync('npm ls --prod --json').toString())

  // Only get dependencies for specific top-level modules, if specified.
  const dependencyTreeFiltered = moduleFilter.length
    ? {
        ...dependencyTree,
        dependencies: Object.keys(dependencyTree.dependencies)
          .filter((key) => moduleFilter.includes(key))
          .reduce((obj, key) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
            obj[key] = dependencyTree.dependencies[key]
            return obj
          }, {}),
      }
    : dependencyTree

  const allChildDeps = []
  const getAllChildDependencies = (depTree) => {
    const nextDeps = depTree.dependencies
    if (!nextDeps || !Object.keys(nextDeps).length) {
      return []
    }
    Object.entries(nextDeps).forEach(([childDep, childDepTree]) => {
      allChildDeps.push(childDep)
      getAllChildDependencies(childDepTree)
    })
    return allChildDeps
  }

  return getAllChildDependencies(dependencyTreeFiltered)
}
```