# What are the benefits of using Webpack to bundle backend (Node) code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Related: ["Webpack for back-end?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788142/webpack-for-back-end)

["There's no reason not to use webpack for node/io.js code..."](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I)

["The grand goal of packing an entire application" through weback.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/135)

What is the purpose of using Webpack to bundle server side code?

Are there any advantages of using Webpack + Node as opposed to Node on its own?

- **Hot reload** you say? Is hot reloading really that much better than automatic server restarts (via nodemon or related tools) during development?
- **Aliases** to end the `../../../../` nightmare? There plenty of other [solutions](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520), including the [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

What about if you are building a web app with a Node (Express) backend and a React frontend - specifically, a frontend built with Create React App, which comes with Webpack pre-configured?

**I had updated my question to include the references that had prompted me to ask this question and yet it was still put on hold. Why is this?**

Comment: where are you seeing Webpack used to bundle server-side code?  Do you want to add a reference for where this is suggested as a good thing?

Comment: You mean to tell me you can use Webpack as a server-side build tool without having to bundle code? I thought the main point of Webpack was to generate bundles, so any suggestions for using it with node implicitly suggest bundling. You bring up a good point on my lack of references, I'll update the question soon.