# Is it possible to write a JS library using ES6 modules, but still being able to use it in a NodeJS back-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I would like to write a JavaScript library using ES6 modules to manage submodules. 
I would also like to be able to use it in both front-end applications (with babel and webpack) and NodeJS back-end projects.

Is there a way to "build" the library, written with ES6 modules, in order to use it also as a NodeJS library?

Comment: When you publish your lib you can send your es5 compatible bundle. Also node 8 covers pretty much all es6.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is related with [Webpack for back-end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788142/webpack-for-back-end)

But yes, it is possible. You just need to install babel and webpack and then you will be all set

Answer (score 0):

Yes! webpack supports both `node` and `web` targets! You can find more information about how to set this in your config at webpack.js.org/configuration/target