# Is webpack a suitable tool to bundle a Node.js backend code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK `webpack` implements a module system on the browser, which historically never had a module system.

But `Node.js` has a module system. You can use commonjs `require` or use `ES6 imports` and it will work fine. I've seen lots of posts over the internet on how to implement `webpack` bundling to a Node.js backend  code.

Is this even recommended? Is it a good practice at all?

**I think that there is a clear answer to this question out there. And it's not opinion-based.**

Comment: This question is definitely opinion-based, as it relies on the specific situation you're in and you haven't told us at all what that situation is.  Some folks bundle their Node.js apps to make it easier to distribute/deploy.  There may be other use cases too.  What is your situation?

Comment: why do y ou think you need a server-side bundle?

Comment: I've personally not found any reasons to want to bundle back-end code and it just complicates debugging and troubleshooting since the bundler has repackaged everything.  There are a some people who find some advantages in doing so.  See [Webpack for back-end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788142/webpack-for-back-end) for more info.

Comment: Google is your friend here: [Do you need Webpack for server-side Javascript](https://www.getrevue.co/profile/masteringjs/issues/do-you-need-webpack-for-server-side-javascript-230766) and numerous other links discussing the topic.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks. From the article that you mentioned, I didn't find any concrete reason where one should use `webpack` to bundle server code. Even on `AWS Lambdas`, it mentions that you can't install `npm` dependencies (maybe on older versions), but today this is already possible, as per [AWS Lambda docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html). I guess it's a matter of taste, but so far I'll stick with my conclusion that `webpack` is meant for browser code, because it's an environment that lacks a module system, whilst Node.js has a module system out of the box.

Comment: @cbdeveloper - That is my conclusion too.